# Questions containing links truncated on Stack Exchange "hot questions" page

Tags: bug, status-completed, hot-questions, truncation

The text for certain questions on the "hot questions" page on the Stack Exchange home is being truncated. These questions all contain links early in the question text so presumably this is where the problem lies.

Some examples:

[How do I enable the “extras” repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25692/how-do-i-enable-the-extras-repository)
[image: How do I enable the "extras" repository?]

[How much maintenance?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/2781/how-much-maintenance)
[image: How much maintenance?]

[How to avoid exposing my MAC address when using IPv6?](https://superuser.com/questions/243669/how-to-avoid-exposing-my-mac-address-when-using-ipv6)
[image: How to avoid exposing my MAC address when using IPv6?]

Comment: To close voters: this bug was *fixed*, not *no longer reproducible*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the debugging help -- you're absolutely right: we were trimming question bodies (to 300 chars) before caching them, so long html tags early in the question were throwing off the logic.

This is fixed now for future questions (some already-cached questions will still look prematurely truncated for a short while longer).